# python complex list object to dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I wanted to create a dataframe by expanding the child list object along with parent objects.

Obviously trying pd.DataFrame(lst) does not work as it creates data frame with three columns only and keeps the child object as one column.

Is it possible to do this in one line instead of iterating through list to expand each child object? Thank you in advance.

I have a list object in python like this:

```
lst =   [
        {
            'id': 'rec1', 
            'fields': {
                'iso': 'US', 
                'name': 'U S', 
                'lat': '38.9051', 
                'lon': '-77.0162'
                },
            'createdTime': '2021-03-16T13:03:24.000Z'
        }, 
        {
            'id': 'rec2', 
            'fields': {'iso': 'HK', 'name': 'China', 'lat': '0.0', 'lon': '0.0'},
            'createdTime': '2021-03-16T13:03:24.000Z'
        }
    ]
```

explected dataframe:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(lst)
print (df)
     id               createdTime fields.iso fields.name fields.lat fields.lon
0  rec1  2021-03-16T13:03:24.000Z         US         U S    38.9051   -77.0162
1  rec2  2021-03-16T13:03:24.000Z         HK       China        0.0        0.0
```